# How can I prove this identity?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I'm considering the stochastic tree. When root node is activated, the $n$ child nodes get the signal. But the probability of activation is $p$. $d$ is index of layer and starts from 1 that is indicating the first child layer. The activated nodes of layer $d$ is called $a_d$. The probability that a layer $d$ has no activated nodes is
$$
P(a_d=0) = q^n(r(r(r(...r(r+1)^n...+1)^n+1)^n+1)^n+1)^n
$$
where $q=1-p$ and $r=pq^{n-1}$. The $n$ power related to $r$ is repeated $d$ times. What I want to know is the analytic expression of $P(a_d=0)$ or at least proving,
$$
\lim_{d \rightarrow \infty} P(a_d=0)=1
$$
I conducted numerical calculation and what I got is that when $np < 1$ the sequence is converge to 1 very fast($d=10^1$). When $np = 1$, converge speed is decreased($d=10^5$). When $np > 1$, the sequence seems not converge to 1($d=10^6$, the value was 0.16).

Comment: May you give a title that is a bit less generic? Plus, if this is from a paper, book or notes, please include a link to the original source.

Comment: I VTC'd as suitable for Mathematics SE and I note you have already [cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544961/how-can-i-calculate-this-repeating-power) it to there.  Cross posting is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Quillo Sorry, I didn't refer to any paper or other literature but thought myself. So I couldn't find proper title or term for this process.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I'm sorry I didn't know that. But why the cross posting be discouraged?

Comment: This is a very special case of a [Galton-Watson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process). You can find it discussed in most probability textbooks. (And indeed, the probability that the layer $k$ has no activated node tends to $1$ as $k\to\infty$ if and only if $pn\leq 1$.)

Comment: "I'm considering the stochastic tree".. there are literally thousands of models, which model do you refer to? How do you get the first expression? What EXACTLY is $p$?

Comment: @YvanVelenik I salute to your level of knowledge.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cross posting is dealt with on [a post on the Physics Meta SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7122/cross-posting-similar-same-question-on-two-se-sites) where we deal with issues specific to how the Physics SE site runs. e.g. general policy, how specific rules are implemented, that kind of thing.  Basically cross posting causes duplication of effort and typically people on one site are not aware of perfectly good answers on the other.